# Neighbors with very different labels

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

The cells of a square $2011$ by $2011$  array are labelled with the integers $1,2,\dots, 2011^2$ in such a way that every label is used exactly once. We identity the top and bottom edges and the left and right edges to wrap the array to form a torus or donut shape.

What is the largest positive integer $M$ such that, no matter which labelling we choose, there exist two neighboring cells with the difference of their labels at least $M$?

Two cells are neighbors if either their $x$ or $y$ coordinates are the same and the other coordinate is  $\pm 1$  when taken modulo $2011$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Problem 6 from the 4th Romanian Master of Mathematics Competition.
Its solution is [here](http://rmms.lbi.ro/rmm2011/_dwl/Sols2011D2.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. It's a very nice problem it turns out.